# Derivative of a composite function on vector spaces

Tags: calculus

I recently came across this little identity while reading a book on Lie algebras, and it seems so simple but I seem to have forgotten most of my elementary calculus.

Given a linear map $\phi: V \rightarrow W$ where $V$ and $W$ are finite dimensional vector spaces. Let $\gamma:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow V$ be a smooth $V$-valued function of a real variable $t$. I'm trying to prove the following:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt} \phi(\gamma(t)) = \phi\left(\frac{d\gamma(t)}{dt}\right) \quad \forall \, t \in \mathbb{R}
\end{align}
$$

The problem in the book suggests using the limit definition of the derivative, which seems quite elementary but I haven't been able to figure it out still. I apologize if this is a duplicate, I haven't been able to figure out a name for this identity.

Comment: And, what is the limit definition of the derivative that is in the book?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By writing out the definition of the derivative and using the linearity of $\phi$ we can get:
$$\frac{d}{dt}\phi(\gamma(t))=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\phi(\gamma(t+h))-\phi(\gamma(t))}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\phi\bigg( \frac{\gamma(t+h)-\gamma(t)}{h}\bigg). $$
Since $V,W$ are finite dimensional $\phi$ is continuous so we can bring the limit inside:$$\frac{d}{dt}\phi(\gamma(t))=\lim_{h\to 0}\phi\bigg( \frac{\gamma(t+h)-\gamma(t)}{h}\bigg) = \phi\bigg(\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\gamma(t+h)-\gamma(t)}{h}\bigg) = \phi\bigg( \frac{d\gamma(t)}{d t}\bigg).$$